# Running EXE from buffer in memory

Tags: c++, exe

i'm trying to make exe packer
5

1. extract exe to buffer(in my case: vector)
2. add new section
3. get offset of new EP and run

but after call newmain i got `0xC0000005`

main.cpp:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z3sYKwN0)

```
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include "main.h"
typedef struct _BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY
{
    WORD Offset : 12;
    WORD Type : 4;
} BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY;

BOOL applyRelocBlock(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY* block, size_t entriesNum, DWORD page, PVOID newBase)
{
    PVOID ImageBaseAddress = NtCurrentTeb()->Peb->ImageBaseAddress;
    BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY* entry = block;

    for (int i = 0; i < entriesNum; i++)
    {
        DWORD offset = entry->Offset;
        DWORD type = entry->Type;
        if (entry == NULL || type == 0 || offset == 0)
        {
            //printf("Applied relocations: %d\n", i);
            return TRUE; //finish
        }
        if (type != 3)
        {
            printf("Not supported relocations format at %d: %d\n", i, type);
            return FALSE;
        }
        uint32_t* relocateAddr = (uint32_t*)((ULONG_PTR)newBase + page + offset);
        (*relocateAddr) = ((*relocateAddr) - (ULONG_PTR)ImageBaseAddress) + (ULONG_PTR)newBase;
        entry = (BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY*)((ULONG_PTR)entry + sizeof(uint16_t));
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL applyRelocations(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders, PVOID newBase)
{
    PVOID ImageBaseAddress = NtCurrentTeb()->Peb->ImageBaseAddress;
    //fetch relocation table from current image:
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocDir = NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];
    if (relocDir.VirtualAddress == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot relocate - application have no relocation table!");
        return FALSE;
    }
    DWORD maxSize = relocDir.Size;
    DWORD parsedSize = 0;

    DWORD relocAddr = relocDir.VirtualAddress;
    IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION* reloc = NULL;

    while (parsedSize < maxSize)
    {
        reloc = (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION*)(relocAddr + parsedSize + (ULONG_PTR)ImageBaseAddress);
        parsedSize += reloc->SizeOfBlock;

        if (reloc->VirtualAddress == NULL || reloc->SizeOfBlock == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        printf("RelocBlock: %p %p\n", reloc->VirtualAddress, reloc->SizeOfBlock);

        size_t entriesNum = (reloc->SizeOfBlock - 2 * sizeof(uint32_t)) / sizeof(uint16_t);
        DWORD page = reloc->VirtualAddress;

        BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY* block = (BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY*)((ULONG_PTR)reloc + sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(uint32_t));
        if (applyRelocBlock(block, entriesNum, page, newBase) == FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

bool checkLibs()
{
    return load_ntdll_functions() && load_kernel32_functions();
}

bool mapAndRun()
{
    HANDLE hSection = NULL;

    PVOID ImageBaseAddress = NtCurrentTeb()->Peb->ImageBaseAddress;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders = RtlImageNtHeader(ImageBaseAddress);

    if (NtHeaders == NULL)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] RtlImageNtHeader failed, error : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER MaximumSize;
    ULONG ImageSize = NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;

    MaximumSize.LowPart = ImageSize;
    MaximumSize.HighPart = 0;

    NTSTATUS Status = NULL;

    if ((Status = ZwCreateSection(&hSection, SECTION_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &MaximumSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, NULL)) != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] ZwCreateSection failed, status : %x\n", Status);
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Section handle: %x\n", hSection);

    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
    PVOID pSectionBaseAddress = NULL;
    SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;
    DWORD dwInheritDisposition = 1; //VIEW_SHARE

    // map the section in context of current process:
    if ((Status = NtMapViewOfSection(hSection, GetCurrentProcess(), &pSectionBaseAddress, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ViewSize, dwInheritDisposition, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)) != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] NtMapViewOfSection failed, status : %x\n", Status);
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Created new section, BaseAddress: %p ViewSize: %p\n", pSectionBaseAddress, ViewSize);
    printf("Mapping into: %p <- current image: %p %p\n", pSectionBaseAddress, ImageBaseAddress, ImageSize);
    RtlCopyMemory(pSectionBaseAddress, ImageBaseAddress, ImageSize);

    ZwClose(hSection);
    hSection = NULL;
    if (applyRelocations(NtHeaders, pSectionBaseAddress) == FALSE) {
        printf("Applying relocations failed, cannot continue!");
        ZwTerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), STATUS_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Applied relocations!\n");

    //

    std::vector<unsigned char> extractedData = unpackExe(); //packe exe

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
    memcpy(&IDH, &extractedData[0], sizeof(IDH));
    memcpy(&INH, (void*)((DWORD)&extractedData[0] + IDH.e_lfanew), sizeof(INH));

    LARGE_INTEGER MaximumSizeEX;
    ULONG ImageSizeEX = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;

    MaximumSizeEX.LowPart = ImageSizeEX;
    MaximumSizeEX.HighPart = 0;
    ULONG_PTR exEP = INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

    ULONG_PTR offsetFromBase = exEP - (ULONG_PTR)ImageBaseAddress;
    printf("extracted EP offset: %p\n", offsetFromBase);

    ULONG_PTR newMain = ((ULONG_PTR)pSectionBaseAddress + offsetFromBase);
    printf("extracted EP address in new section: %p\n", newMain);

    __asm {
        call newMain
    };

    return true;
}

bool mapAndExecute()
{
    if (checkLibs())
    {
        if (mapAndRun())
        {
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    mapAndExecute();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

main.h:pastebin: pastebin.com/Spc5WTsQ

```
    #pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#if !defined NTSTATUS
typedef LONG NTSTATUS;
#endif

#define STATUS_SUCCESS 0
#define STATUS_FAILURE (-1)
#define NtCurrentProcess() ((HANDLE)-1)

typedef struct _CLIENT_ID
{
    HANDLE UniqueProcess;
    HANDLE UniqueThread;
} CLIENT_ID, *PCLIENT_ID;

typedef LONG NTSTATUS, *PNTSTATUS;
typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA
{
    ULONG               Length;
    BOOLEAN             Initialized;
    PVOID               SsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY          InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY          InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY          InInitializationOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;

typedef struct _PEB
{
    BYTE                         Reserved1[2];       /*  00 */
    BYTE                         BeingDebugged;      /*  02 */
    BYTE                         Reserved2[5];       /*  03 */
    HMODULE                      ImageBaseAddress;   /*  08 */
    PPEB_LDR_DATA                LdrData;            /*  0c */
    DWORD                        ProcessParameters;  /*  10 */
    PVOID                        __pad_14;           /*  14 */
    HANDLE                       ProcessHeap;        /*  18 */
    BYTE                         __pad_1c[36];       /*  1c */
    DWORD                        TlsBitmap;          /*  40 */
    ULONG                        TlsBitmapBits[2];   /*  44 */
    BYTE                         __pad_4c[24];       /*  4c */
    ULONG                        NumberOfProcessors; /*  64 */
    BYTE                         __pad_68[128];      /*  68 */
    PVOID                        Reserved3[59];      /*  e8 */
    ULONG                        SessionId;          /* 1d4 */
} PEB, *PPEB;

typedef struct _TEB
{
    NT_TIB          Tib;                        /* 000 */
    PVOID           EnvironmentPointer;         /* 01c */
    CLIENT_ID       ClientId;                   /* 020 */
    PVOID           ActiveRpcHandle;            /* 028 */
    PVOID           ThreadLocalStoragePointer;  /* 02c */
    PPEB            Peb;                        /* 030 */
    ULONG           LastErrorValue;             /* 034 */
    BYTE            __pad038[140];              /* 038 */
    ULONG           CurrentLocale;              /* 0c4 */
    BYTE            __pad0c8[1752];             /* 0c8 */
    PVOID           Reserved2[278];             /* 7a0 */
    UNICODE_STRING  StaticUnicodeString;        /* bf8 used by advapi32 */
    WCHAR           StaticUnicodeBuffer[261];   /* c00 used by advapi32 */
    PVOID           DeallocationStack;          /* e0c */
    PVOID           TlsSlots[64];               /* e10 */
    LIST_ENTRY      TlsLinks;                   /* f10 */
    PVOID           Reserved4[26];              /* f18 */
    PVOID           ReservedForOle;             /* f80 Windows 2000 only */
    PVOID           Reserved5[4];               /* f84 */
    PVOID           TlsExpansionSlots;          /* f94 */
} TEB, *PTEB;

typedef
void
(*PKNORMAL_ROUTINE) (
    void* NormalContext,
    void* SystemArgument1,
    void* SystemArgument2
    );

typedef struct {
    int info;
    PKNORMAL_ROUTINE fun;
} *PIO_STATUS_BLOCK;

// Make sure we print the __stdcall properly
typedef
void
(__stdcall *PIO_APC_ROUTINE) (
    void* ApcContext,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    long Reserved
    );


#if !defined PROCESSINFOCLASS
typedef LONG PROCESSINFOCLASS;
#endif

#if !defined THREADINFOCLASS
typedef LONG THREADINFOCLASS;
#endif

#if !defined PPEB
typedef struct _PEB *PPEB;
#endif

#if !defined PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION {
    PVOID Reserved1;
    PPEB PebBaseAddress;
    PVOID Reserved2[2];
    ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID Reserved3;
} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
#endif;

/*
typedef LONG NTSTATUS, *PNTSTATUS;
typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
USHORT Length;
USHORT MaximumLength;
PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;
*/

typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {
    ULONG Length;
    HANDLE RootDirectory;
    PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    ULONG Attributes;
    PVOID SecurityDescriptor;
    PVOID SecurityQualityOfService;
} OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, *POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI * PFN_ZWQUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)(HANDLE, PROCESSINFOCLASS,
    PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);

//ntdll api:
NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwQueryInformationProcess)(
    HANDLE  ProcessHandle,
    PROCESSINFOCLASS  ProcessInformationClass,
    PVOID  ProcessInformation,
    ULONG  ProcessInformationLength,
    PULONG  ReturnLength  OPTIONAL
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwCreateSection)(
    __out    PHANDLE            SectionHandle,
    __in     ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
    __in POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    __in PLARGE_INTEGER     MaximumSize,
    __in     ULONG              SectionPageProtection,
    __in     ULONG              AllocationAttributes,
    __in HANDLE             FileHandle
    );


NTSTATUS(NTAPI *NtMapViewOfSection)(
    __in        HANDLE          SectionHandle,
    __in        HANDLE          ProcessHandle,
    __inout     PVOID           *BaseAddress,
    __in        ULONG_PTR       ZeroBits,
    __in        SIZE_T          CommitSize,
    __inout  PLARGE_INTEGER  SectionOffset,
    __inout     PSIZE_T         ViewSize,
    __in        DWORD InheritDisposition,
    __in        ULONG           AllocationType,
    __in        ULONG           Win32Protect
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwCreateThreadEx) (
    __out PHANDLE ThreadHandle,
    __in ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    __in POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    __in HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    __in PVOID StartRoutine,
    __in PVOID Argument,
    __in ULONG CreateFlags,
    __in ULONG_PTR ZeroBits,
    __in SIZE_T StackSize,
    __in SIZE_T MaximumStackSize,
    __in PVOID AttributeList
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwUnmapViewOfSection) (
    __in     HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    __in PVOID  BaseAddress
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwClose) (
    __in HANDLE Handle
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwTerminateProcess) (
    __in HANDLE   ProcessHandle,
    __in     NTSTATUS ExitStatus
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *NtQueueApcThread)(
    __in HANDLE ThreadHandle,
    __in PVOID ApcRoutine,
    __in PVOID ApcRoutineContext OPTIONAL,
    __in PVOID ApcStatusBlock OPTIONAL,
    __in ULONG ApcReserved OPTIONAL
    );

NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ZwSetInformationThread) (
    __in HANDLE ThreadHandle,
    __in THREADINFOCLASS ThreadInformationClass,
    __in PVOID ThreadInformation,
    __in ULONG ThreadInformationLength
    );

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(NTAPI *RtlImageNtHeader) (
    __in PVOID ModuleAddress
    );


//kernel32 api
BOOL
(WINAPI *CreateProcessInternalW)(HANDLE hToken,
    LPCWSTR lpApplicationName,
    LPWSTR lpCommandLine,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    BOOL bInheritHandles,
    DWORD dwCreationFlags,
    LPVOID lpEnvironment,
    LPCWSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
    LPSTARTUPINFOW lpStartupInfo,
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation,
    PHANDLE hNewToken
    );
```

trying to adoptate source from here

> https://github.com/hasherezade/snippets/tree/master/inject4

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? `0xC0000005` is an access error code exception - check array/memory access.

Comment: Yes, I got this exception in vs. But where is error then? I'm trying to call wrong pointer as new entry point?

Comment: And, the answer to all those come down to: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius :  You are right, Windows will not allow you to execute "code" in the data space of another application - for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

The data you have loaded is in the loading application's data space and execution of data is blocked in modern memory protected operating systems - because that was previously a common and rather easy exploit for viruses.

In order to run, an executable must have been loaded and located by the operating system.

Comment: I agree. You can of course write the executable's data to a file and that execute it using CreateProcess or ShellExecute and it will work, but only because it was saved to a physical file first.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Study the API VirtualProtect(). If you use it correctly and set Execute permission to a page in memory, you CAN execute your own dynamic code in memory. By the way: There are JavaScript compilers which do exactly this.

Comment: @Elmue : not _completely_ wrong then, just the last sentence? It remains the reason the OP's method will not work. Indeed a JIT compiler must be able to do that. You should post an answer elaborating your solution.

Comment: Hello Clifford. I would like to post a working solution. If I had. I'am searching for one month now the internet up and down and could not find it. The process hollowing technique which you find frequently fails to start Calc.exe on Windows 10. And fancycode which loads a process to the memory of an already running process has the same problem. I posted details here: https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule/issues/102

Answer (score -1):

It would be impossible to run an executable from memory without having the executable data reside in a physical file. Windows won't allow it. No windows API provides mechanism to execute file directly from memory. All windows API like CreateProcess() or ShellExcute() require a physical file to be present. If there **is** a way, it would be considered a vulnerability and will be soon patched.

Comment: If a the page that contains code has execute permissions then the code can be executed.

Comment: Steve, you posted an example for calling a function that is stored in memory, Not a executing a program (process).

Comment: @Michael: You are right: There is no API for that. But your conclusion that this is impossible is completely wrong. You can write your own loader to memory. See fancycode/MemoryModule on Github which does exactly this.

Comment: @Elmue, I know this project but it won't allow running an .exe from memory. Is tries to load a DLL.

Comment: It seems you don't know fancycode. Starting an EXE from memory is implemented. However the code to adjust the PEB is missing. But even after adding this you cannot start every EXE. Some work (e.g. the 32 bit Calc.exe and Notepad.exe on Windows XP and Windows 7) but other EXE and 64 bit EXE's won't start from memory or crash later. There are more adaptions which have to be done. But as all this stuff is highly undocumented you have to be a real cracker (or a professional malware writer) to get this working.

Comment: I posted the missing code to adjust the PEB here: https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule/issues/102

Comment: @Elmie, (Almost) No one uses XP or even Windows 7 these days, so please let me know if you manage to execute even just a skeleton .exe on a x64 Windows 10...

Comment: I know that today Windows XP and 7 are out (although I like 7 much more than 10). But if you work on this undocumented stuff it is far easier to find information about the internals of Windows XP than Windows 10. For example studying the source code of the ReactOS project is great for getting an idea what goes on inside Windows. But it is sadly based on Windows XP. All these structures like PEB etc become more complex with each Windows version. So getting it to run on XP is a first step.

Comment: @Elmue, I am now following you at github and will check the repo with the code in your comments.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how to post a large code snippet in response to a request that was a remark. Michael Haephrati asked for an x64 example of executing data as x64 code. Here's the code (x64 only for this code, the calling conventions differ in 32 bit code):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int(*PMULFUNC)(int l, int r);

PMULFUNC buildFunction()
{
    LPVOID pMem = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 6, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    unsigned char *pNext = (unsigned char *)pMem;

    *pNext = 0x8b; ++pNext;     // mov eax, ecx
    *pNext = 0xc1; ++pNext;

    *pNext = 0x0f; ++pNext;     // imul eax, edx
    *pNext = 0xaf; ++pNext;
    *pNext = 0xc2; ++pNext;

    *pNext = 0xc3; ++pNext;     // ret

    return (PMULFUNC)pMem;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    PMULFUNC pMul = buildFunction();

    int l = 5;
    for (int r=1; r<=12; ++r)
    {
        cout << l << "x" << r << "=" << (*pMul)(l, r) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

typedef int(__stdcall *PMULFUNC)(int l, int r);

PMULFUNC buildFunction()
{
    LPVOID pMem = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 6, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    unsigned char *pNext = (unsigned char *)pMem;

    *pNext = 0x8b; ++pNext;     // mov eax, ecx
    *pNext = 0xc1; ++pNext;

    *pNext = 0x0f; ++pNext;     // imul eax, edx
    *pNext = 0xaf; ++pNext;
    *pNext = 0xc2; ++pNext;

    *pNext = 0xc3; ++pNext;     // ret

    return (PMULFUNC)pMem;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    PMULFUNC pMul = buildFunction();

    int l = 5;
    for (int r=1; r<=12; ++r)
    {
        cout << l << "x" << r << "=" << (*pMul)(l, r) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In response to the specific question, it's possible but advanced. EXEs aren't simply copied into memory: references to other DLL's are resolved, sections that are adjacent in the image may be separated in memory, and many other things. In short you would have to re-implement the loader. But one thing is certain, if a page has the correct permissions it can be executed,

Comment: Steve, thanks! I built your code. You are indeed successfully executing a function from memory. It prints:
5, 10, 15, ...

However the question was about running an executable from memory. If you manage to do so, you would launch a new process.

To demonstrate such thing you need to create a simple executable. Convert the .exe file into an array of chars. Load this array into memory during runtime and execute it as a new process (using CreateProcess() or a similar method). Doing so without saving it into a file will prove that its possible.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: The OP never claimed, that they needed to create a new process. They have asked how to unpack code, and execute it. This can be done in-process, as long as you resolve imports and perform the required relocations. The required information is stored in the PE image. Even if they need to create a new process, they can map the local process' address space into the newly created process. This is tedious, yet possible.

Comment: @Steve you are wrong about that. First the title of the question is "Running EXE from buffer in memory" (so if I am wrong, the title should be changed). Second, the question is about executing a PE. A PE means that a separate program is to be ran (which is also the purpose of "packers" as mentioned in the question). To do so, you need to create a separate process.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrat It wasn't me that made that comment:)

Comment: Sorry @Steve, my bad. In any case, my comment (and my answer) still stand..

Comment: @IInspectable, I disagree. Regardless of the method (creating a new process, hijacking an existing process, via DLL Injection, or using the current process), the goal of the question is "Running EXE from buffer in memory" and that is not allowed by Windows, as I explained in my answer. Loading a DLL from memory may be possible, as Joachim Bauch showed here: https://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: The only difference between an EXE and a DLL is a flag in an optional PE header. If a solution exists using a DLL, then that solution applies to an EXE as well. I don't know what you are trying to say by *"is not allowed by Windows"*. Surely, you can call `VirtualProtect` on any memory page, and mark it as executable code.

Comment: If you can show a POC, go ahead and prove me wrong by pointing out a fully tested and working source code that loads an executable from memory and runs it. I claim its impossible unless a vulnerability is used. For the purpose of discussion, take calc.exe, stored it as an array of chars inside another program and have that program run it from memory.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: The POC is right in front of you. The kernel calls [ZwMapViewOfSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481.aspx) to map the executable image into the address space. The kernel could just as well allocate memory, and write to it instead. So running a process from memory only *is* possible. This does not constitute a vulnerability either; calling code still needs the required access rights.

Comment: @IInspectable - This is not a POC. It is impossible to run an EXE from memory. I am sorry I don't have more time to explain to you why...

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: *"I don't have time"* is not a very helpful comment. If you cannot explain, why this were impossible, then maybe you are not very good at explaining things, or you are wrong. Given your understanding of how security works, the latter looks to be very likely.